# Adding features in the layer with reference to another layer

Tags: python, qgis-2.4

I have built a tool for creating line in the exact center of two selected lines through this code:

```
import math 



def mainCl():
    ftr_geom = []
    select = iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures()
    for ftr in select:
        geom = ftr.geometry()
        if geom.type() == QGis.Line:        
            f_geom = geom.asPolyline()
            ftr_geom.append(f_geom)

l1x1=ftr_geom[0][0][0]
l1y1=ftr_geom[0][0][1]
l1x2=ftr_geom[0][1][0]
l1y2=ftr_geom[0][1][1]
l2x1=ftr_geom[1][0][0]
l2y1=ftr_geom[1][0][1]
l2x2=ftr_geom[1][1][0]
l2y2=ftr_geom[1][1][1]
pr = iface.activeLayer().dataProvider()

d1=math.sqrt(math.pow((l2x1-l1x1),2)+math.pow((l2y1-l1y1),2))
d2=math.sqrt(math.pow((l2x2-l1x1),2)+math.pow((l2y2-l1y1),2))
d3=math.sqrt(math.pow((l2x1-l1x2),2)+math.pow((l2y1-l1y2),2))
d4=math.sqrt(math.pow((l2x2-l1x2),2)+math.pow((l2y2-l1y2),2))

if d1<d2:
    case1()

else:
    case2()


def mid(pt1, pt2):
   x = (pt1.x() + pt2.x())/2
   y = (pt1.y() + pt2.y())/2
   return QgsPoint(x,y)


def case1():
    ftr_geom = []
    select = iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures()
    for ftr in select:
        geom = ftr.geometry()
        if geom.type() == QGis.Line:        
            f_geom = geom.asPolyline()
            ftr_geom.append(f_geom)

l1x1=ftr_geom[0][0][0]
l1y1=ftr_geom[0][0][1]
l1x2=ftr_geom[0][1][0]
l1y2=ftr_geom[0][1][1]
l2x1=ftr_geom[1][0][0]
l2y1=ftr_geom[1][0][1]
l2x2=ftr_geom[1][1][0]
l2y2=ftr_geom[1][1][1]
pr = iface.activeLayer().dataProvider()

midpt1= mid(QgsPoint(l1x1,l1y1), QgsPoint(l2x1,l2y1))
midpt2= mid(QgsPoint(l1x2,l1y2), QgsPoint(l2x2,l2y2))
nwl = QgsFeature()
nwl.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([midpt1,
midpt2]))
pr.addFeatures( [ nwl ] )


def case2():
    ftr_geom = []
    select = iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures()
    for ftr in select:
        geom = ftr.geometry()
        if geom.type() == QGis.Line:        
            f_geom = geom.asPolyline()
            ftr_geom.append(f_geom)

l1x1=ftr_geom[0][0][0]
l1y1=ftr_geom[0][0][1]
l1x2=ftr_geom[0][1][0]
l1y2=ftr_geom[0][1][1]
l2x1=ftr_geom[1][0][0]
l2y1=ftr_geom[1][0][1]
l2x2=ftr_geom[1][1][0]
l2y2=ftr_geom[1][1][1]
pr = iface.activeLayer().dataProvider()

midpt1= mid(QgsPoint(l1x1,l1y1), QgsPoint(l2x2,l2y2))
midpt2= mid(QgsPoint(l1x2,l1y2), QgsPoint(l2x1,l2y1))
nwl = QgsFeature()
nwl.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([midpt1,
midpt2]))
pr.addFeatures( [ nwl ] )

mainCl()
```

Now I want to modify my tool..I want that I select a layer and select its two lines..The new centerline should be drawn in the layer of my choice not in the same layer..To choose the layer in which I want to draw line is through this select box:

[image]

And the layers it loads should be the map layers I added in the layer box..
Overall task will be that I select two lines in one active layer and the centerline will be drawn in the the layer I selected in that box.

Can anybody help me how to perform this task?